# Embed Facebook Framework in iOS8 embedded Framework

Tags: facebook, api, ios8, facebook-login, ios-frameworks

I am trying to include Facebook.framework in an iOS8 embedded library with a few classes that handles login and open graph sharing. The problem I am facing is how to modify the info.plist of the embedded framework so that it changes the Facebook key values for different applications without exposing the info.plist file of the embedded framework?

Is there a way to create a dependency on external key value pairs maybe in the host project's info.plist? Or is there a way that I am not aware of to do so.

Thanks